# Ошибка при записи в файл

Tags: visual-c++, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <clocale>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    ofstream f;


    bool right=false;
    bool log_true=false;
    bool pas_true=false;

    int eq1,eq2,i,er_log=0;  //сравнение лог/пас
    int result;
    int result2;
    int put;
    char hp[4][16];

    ifstream log, pas;

    char login[16],logi[16];
    char passworld[16],pasw[16];

    i=0;
    ////////////

        case 1:{
            pas.open("pas.txt",ios_base::in);
            for(int i2=0; i2<5;i2++){
                pas.getline(hp[i2], sizeof(login));
            }
            cout<<"Введите новый пароль"<<endl;
            cin>>hp[eq1];
            pas.close();

            pas.open("pas.txt",  ios::app | ios::trunc);
            for(int i3=0; i3<5;i3++)
            {
                pas << hp[i3] << endl;    //.... Строка ошибки......
            }


            break;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

**В данном коде возникает множество ошибок(несколько из них):**

> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\ostream(726): см. объявление "std::operator <<" 1>lab1.cpp(134): error C2784: std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *):
>   не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для
>   "std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &" из "std::ifstream"
>
> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\ostream(679): см. объявление "std::operator <<" 1>lab1.cpp(134): error C2784: std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *):
>   не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для
>   "std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &" из "std::ifstream"
>
> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\ostream(679): см. объявление "std::operator <<" 1>lab1.cpp(134): error C2784: std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *):
>   не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для
>   "std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &" из "std::ifstream"
>
> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\ostream(679): см. объявление "std::operator <<" 1>lab1.cpp(134): error C2784: std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *):
>   не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для
>   "std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &" из "std::ifstream"
>
> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\ostream(679): см. объявление "std::operator <<" 1>lab1.cpp(134): error C2784: std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>
>   &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *):
>   не удалось вывести аргумент шаблон для
>   "std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &" из "std::ifstream"
>
> 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\include\ostream(679): см. объявление "std::operator <<"
>
> 1>lab1.cpp(134): error C2676: бинарный "<<": "std::ifstream" не
>   определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к
>   встроенному оператору

**Все ошибки относятся к помеченной комментарием строке.**

**Весь код я не скидывал, только инклуды, переменные и кейс с ошибкой**

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Вы не верно используете класс ifstream: этот класс предназначен **только** для чтения данных из потока! Вы же пытаетесь вызвать оператор вывода в поток (operator << в строке "pas << hp[i3] << endl" ), который естественно отсутствует. 

Чтобы исправить Ваш код Вам необходимо использовать класс ofstream.

Comment: Так же у вас в циклах идет выход за границы массива.
У вас массив нумеруется от 0 до 3 так как тока 4 элемента, а в цикле проходите от 0 до 4, а это уже 5 получается.

Answer (score 3):

`ifstream` только для чтения из файла используется, а у вас в той строке `pas << hp[i3] << endl;` используется для записи, при этом в строке `pas.getline(hp[i2], sizeof(login));` этот же поток используется для чтения, поэтому если нужно одновременно уметь читать и записывать из файла, используйте `fstream`.

`fstream` – для чтения и для записи данных (двунаправленный обмен).

Comment: Разве в приведенном коде ***pas*** это не есть объект ***fstream***?

Comment: Когда рефакторил его код и исправлял ошибку, случайно не все изменения логики кода вернул :) например, у меня там еще `switch` торчал. Поправлю -- а то нехорошо получается :)